# Remove Duplicate Row Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to remove duplicates from my table (user_info).  I always want to remove the row with the id column that is lower of the two rows being returned from my select/having query below.  Any ideas on how to write the delete statement to remove the duplicates (lower user_info.id column) from the results of my select/having query below?  I'm using Oracle 11g.

**user_info table structure:**

```
id (unique primary key number 10 generated by sequence)
user_id (number 10)
first_name (varchar2)
last_name (varchar2)
```

**data example:**

```
id      user_id
______  ___________
37265   1455
265798  1455
```

**sql to show duplicates:**

```
select user_id, count(*)
  from user_info
 group by user_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Can there be more than 2 duplicate rows?

Comment: no there are only 2 max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this to show you only the duplicates

```
Select user_id, count(*) NumRows, Min(Id) SmallestId, Max(Id) LargestId
From user_info
Group by user_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This will show you the min and max for each `user_id` (with the same value for SmallestId and LargestId if there are no duplicates.

```
Select user_id, count(*) NumRows, Min(Id) SmallestId, Max(Id) LargestId
From user_info
Group by user_id
```

For a User, you want to keep the MaxId and Delete everything else.  So you can write a DELETE statement to be

```
DELETE From user_info
Where Id Not IN
(
    Select Max(Id)
    From user_info
    Group by user_id
)
```

This will get the

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
DELETE 
FROM user_info
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM user_info
    GROUP BY user_id);
```

This query will delete all the duplicate rows except the `user_id` row with maximum `id`.

Here's a **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbad4/1)** which demonstrates the delete.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Thank you for your feedback. The OP does want "remove the duplicates (lower user_info.id column)" So, the larger of the two IDs hs to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table test;
/

create table test
(
ids number,
user_id number
);
/


insert into test
values(37265,1455);
/

insert into test
values(265798,1455);
/


select * from test;

delete from test t
where t.ids  < (select max(ids) from test t1 where T1.USER_ID= T.USER_ID)
```

This query employs the sub query to do the same !